# Python Selenium and GeckoDriver different computer issue

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

My desktop computer runs everything perfectly but when running program on my laptop caused issues.

I am working on a program that clicks a size on a website and it gets the SKU for that size. However, I keep getting an error in the HTML inspector and it is preventing the SKU from changing.

I believe this is the error that occurs everytime a click a new size
Uncaught TypeError: _.intersection is not a function

For some reason it can’t find this function on my laptop but does on my desktop?

I have installed the same versions of Firefox, geckodriver, and python on both computers. I even transferred my Firefox profile to my laptop.

Comment: seems like a client-side error with one of the trackers at the site... Does it appear when you navigate to the site manually?

Comment: @pcalkins When I navigate to the site manually it works perfectly. It actually even works when im debugging into the site with python debugger, up until that block of code I linked. About then it stops working as expected.

Comment: the tracker script may be choking on Selenium's user-agent...  pure guess.  Not even sure it's caused by the tracker.

Comment: are you using the default pageLoadStrategy?  It's possible this could be caused by performing some action before the page has fully loaded a remote JS resource.... though in the code above you aren't performing any clicks.

Comment: I do perform a click on the size, but seems weird it works perfectly on my home computer and not my work computer. Ill look into the default pageLoadStrategy you are talking about and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I didn't realize same code was working at home but not on work computer.  It's likely the work computer is just blocking the tracker and a dev-mode launched Firefox will show the error, while normal session wouldn't.  You might try/catch the click() call to see what shows up there...

Comment: @pcalkins The click doesn't cause an issue in the program though. The click actually works successfully, it shows it on the webpage and doesn't doesn't throw an error in my program.

But for some reason the event/function that is called when the button is clicked can't be found. I have experienced with time.sleep() but it doesn't seem like it's a timing issue.

Comment: right... the tracker may be hooked into the events on the page.  (a sort of A/B tool for marketing?)  Again just a guess...